# Unity recognize keyowrds - not recognizing many keywords

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The follwing code works for a few keywords with phrase recognizer, I don't know what the list exactly is but it worked for : up, down, left, right - fine. But when a string array with different keywords like : one/1 , cool , hey etc  - tested it didn't recognize those. I need to know why and Can this be achieved with simple keywords recognizer? Also tried the kwyword recognizer it also not recognizing : "one".

Here's the code:

```
public string[] keywords = new string[] { /*"1",*/ "one", "down", "left", "right" };
public ConfidenceLevel confidence = ConfidenceLevel.Medium;

public Text results;

protected PhraseRecognizer recognizer;
protected string word = "right";

private void Start()
{
    if (keywords != null)
    {
        recognizer = new KeywordRecognizer(keywords, confidence);
        recognizer.OnPhraseRecognized += Recognizer_OnPhraseRecognized;
        recognizer.Start();
    }
}

private void Recognizer_OnPhraseRecognized(PhraseRecognizedEventArgs args)
{
    word = args.text;
    results.text = "You said: <b>" + word + "</b>";
}
```

How can I make it recognize different keywords and also if keywords that has two phrases - like: whats up. Please recommend.

TIA.